# Grails: How to copy/clone/duplicate a row instance

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

In Grails, is there a way to instance a new row using an existing row? Or do I need to loop though the properties and set them all that way?

```
def original=Musicians.get(id);

//want to start with all the same values as original and then modify
def copy=new Musicians(); 
copy.firstName="Example";
copy.lastName='Musician';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy the original properties you can use the `properties` property, like so:

```
def original = Musicians.get(id)
def copy = new Musicians(original.properties)

copy.firstName = 'Example'
copy.lastName = 'Musician'
```

*No semi-colons required ;)*

Comment: but if musicians have: static hasMany = [ letters : Letter], I'm getting error: Found shared references to a collection: com.test.model.Musicians.letters